# bitset: Non-type template argument is not a constant expression

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to solve the [FlippingMatrix coding challenge in Codility](https://app.codility.com/programmers/task/flipping_matrix/) and **(spoiler alert)** ... I devised a solution using `bitset` basically convert the "broken" rows from `vector<int>` into `bitset<M>` and do an XOR looking for the max number of broken but "fixable rows". I don't know yet whether it will work because I'm stuck on the following nuisance.

As we all know [`bitset<M>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) requires the number of bits to be passed as a `constexpr` but I can't do that because the method signature in codility is dynamic `int solution(vector< vector<int> > &A);` so my `M` is:

```
#include <bitset>

template <size_t M>
struct dyna {
    typedef std::bitset<M> bitset_t;
};

// M is A-matrix's number of columns
const size_t M = A[0].size();
dyna<M>::bitset_t bs; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< COMPILER ERROR: Non-type template argument is not a constant expression
```

How can I make this work basically trick the `std::bitset` into receiving A's number of columns `M` as a `constexpr`? I believe I can't use boost's dynamic bitset as bootstrap is not available in codility.

I could also make the `std::bitset<100000>` match the biggest problem size but it would be very wasteful and probably defeat its purpose (biggest problem size i.e. M*N <= 100000 meaning N=100000 is the max possible)

**UPDATE** tested my solution I'm on 82%, failing only the performance hardest test `large_random` of M*N <= 100000. :) I really needed my `bitset` here :P but the idea works.

Comment: If the value is only known at run time there is nothing you can do.  template parameters must be known at compile time.

Comment: Check out `constexpr`

Comment: @ThomasLang That won't help.  The size is coming from a vector passed to the fucntion and function parameters are never constant expressions and `std::vector::size` is not a constant expression anyways so it can't be used.

Comment: @NathanOliver yeah, you're right, my bad.

Comment: We might be looking at a XY problem. Please describe the purpose for this. Also for giving more context, please create a [mcve], because knowing more about `A` might help to see a way to achieve whatever you are trying to use this for.